# Get selected CheckBox values in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a dormitory adding page and this dormitories can have features so I want to use CheckBox list for this.

There is a list of all features a dormitory can have.

```
public class DormFeatureModel
{
    [Key]
    public int FeatureID { get; set; }
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }

    public List<DormHasFeatureModel> DormHasFeature { get; set; }


}
```

Here, too, are features that a dormitory has.

```
public class DormHasFeatureModel
{

    [Key]
    public int HasFeatureID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int FeatureID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DormID { get; set; }

    public virtual DormModel Dorm { get; set; }
    public virtual DormFeatureModel DormFeature { get; set; }


}
```

I can get features list in razor as checkbox
but I can't get selected checkboxes id list(so, FeatureID)

How can I get list in controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a ViewModel that correlates the `Checked` boolean with the `FeatureId`.

```
public class SelectedFeatureViewModel {
     public bool Checked { get; set; }       // to be set by user
     public int FeatureID { get; set; }      // to be populated by GET action
     public string FeatureName { get; set; } // to be populated by GET action
}
```

The GET action creates the main ViewModel and initializes the list of available features (`DormOptions`).

```
public class CreateDormViewModel {

    // used to render the checkboxes, to be initialized in GET controller action
    // also used to bind the checked values back to the controller for POST action
    public ICollection<SelectedFeatureViewModel> DormOptions { get; set; }
}
```

In the Razor markup, bind the checkboxes to the `DormOptions` collection:

```
@model CreateDormViewModel 

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDorm", "DormAdministration", FormMethod.Post)) {

    // use for loop so modelbinding to collection works
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.DormOptions.Count; i++) { 
        <label>@Model.DormOptions[i].FeatureName</label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DormOptions[i].Checked)
        // also post back FeatureId so you can access it in the controller
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DormOptions[i].FeatureID)
        // post back any additional properties that you need to access in the controller
        // or need in order to redraw the view in an error case
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DormOptions[i].FeatureName)
    }
}
```

In the `CreateDorm` POST action, the checkbox values are bound to the ViewModel property you gave in the `CheckBoxFor` lambda, i.e. the `Checked` property in the `DormOptions` collection.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateDorm(CreateDormViewModel postData) {

    var selectedFeatureIds = new List<int>();
    foreach (var option in postData.DormOptions) {
        if (option.Checked) {
            selectedFeatureIds.Add(option.FeatureID);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the list by using the name of the checkboxes, let say your name of the checkboxes is chklstfeatureid then in  controller you can get list like below

```
public actionresult createdorm(list<int> chklstfeatureid)
{

}
```

Thanks